# I try to start my APP with pm2 but it does not start and it restarts infinitely

Tags: node.js, express, discord, discord.js, pm2

npm start will start my app just fine but when I do:

```
pm2 start server.js
```

I get:

```
[PM2] Applying action restartProcessId on app [Huxbot](ids: [ 0 ])
[PM2] [Huxbot](0) ✓
[PM2] Process successfully started
```

[App Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWRlD.png)

in the logs I get:

```
PM2        | 2021-04-19T01:33:15: PM2 log: App [Huxbot] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2021-04-19T01:33:15: PM2 log: App [Huxbot:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2021-04-19T01:33:15: PM2 log: App [Huxbot:0] online
PM2        | 2021-04-19T01:33:23: PM2 log: App [Huxbot:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2021-04-19T01:33:23: PM2 log: App [Huxbot:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2021-04-19T01:33:23: PM2 log: App [Huxbot:0] online
PM2        | 2021-04-19T01:33:31: PM2 log: App [Huxbot:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2021-04-19T01:33:31: PM2 log: App [Huxbot:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2021-04-19T01:33:31: PM2 log: App [Huxbot:0] online
PM2        | 2021-04-19T01:33:39: PM2 log: App [Huxbot:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2021-04-19T01:33:39: PM2 log: App [Huxbot:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2021-04-19T01:33:39: PM2 log: App [Huxbot:0] online
PM2        | 2021-04-19T01:33:46: PM2 log: App [Huxbot:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2021-04-19T01:33:46: PM2 log: App [Huxbot:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2021-04-19T01:33:46: PM2 log: App [Huxbot:0] online
```

here is my package.json:

```
{
"name": "Huxbot",
"version": "3.5.0",
"description": "Huxbot",
"main": "server.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "node server.js"
},
"dependencies": {
"@tohru/gm": "^1.3.0",
"canvas": "^2.6.1",
"canvas-constructor": "^3.2.0",
"cheerio": "^0.22.0",
"discord-youtube-api": "^0.1.0",
"discord.js": "^11.5.1",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"fortnite": "^4.3.2",
"fs": "^0.0.2",
"google": "^2.1.0",
"google-searcher": "^1.0.0",
"google-translate": "^3.0.0",
"google-translate-api": "^2.3.0",
"hive-api": "^1.13.10",
"idiotic-api": "^0.2.11",
"jimp": "^0.12.0",
"js-robloxapi": "^1.0.6",
"kiz": "^1.0.1",
"mal-scraper": "^2.6.9",
"marsnpm": "^0.4.5",
"mega-dtbs": "^0.1.17",
"megadb": "^3.4.0",
"moment": "^2.26.0",
"nekos.life": "^2.0.7",
"node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
"node-opus": "^0.3.3",
"node-osu": "^2.2.0",
"opusscript": "^0.0.7",
"querystring": "^0.2.0",
"request": "^2.88.2",
"retrotext": "^4.0.1",
"simple-youtube-api": "^5.2.1",
"snekfetch": "^4.0.4",
"sqlite": "^4.0.7",
"sqlite3": "^4.2.0",
"superagent": "^5.2.2",
"weather-js": "^2.0.0",
"weeb-sh": "^0.3.3",
"weez": "^1.6.0",
"yandex-translate": "^2.1.3",
"ytdl-core": "^2.1.4",
"ms": "^2.1.2",
"quick.db": "^7.1.1",
"morgan": "^1.10.0",
"path": "^0.12.7",
"ejs": "^3.1.3",
"passport-discord": "^0.1.3",
"passport": "^0.4.1",
"body-parser": "^1.19.0",
"express-session": "^1.17.1",
"twilio": "^4.6.0",
"http": "^0.0.0",
"merge-descriptors": "^1.0.1",
"node-superfetch": "^0.1.10",
"common-tags": "^1.8.0",
"request-promise-native": "^1.0.8"
},
"engines": {
"node": "10.x"
},
"repository": {
"url": "https://glitch.com/edit/#!/hello-sqlite"
},
"license": "MIT",
"keywords": [
"node",
"glitch",
"express"
]
}
```

I currently have the latest version of node and pm2, this happened to me overnight and it hadn't happened to me before
It is worth mentioning that it is a project of a bot for discord, I am hosting it on a VPS.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [this thread](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/4632) and the [process](https://superuser.com/questions/1567652/killing-a-node-process-restarts-with-a-new-pid) to do it.